# Show that $f_n(x) = x^n$ defines a sequence of equicontinuous functions...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, equicontinuity

> Show that $f_n(x) = x^n$ defines a sequence of equicontinuous  functions on the interval (0, 1) that does not admit a subsequence that converges uniformly on (0, 1).

Definitions

Let E be a set formed by real functions defined in $X\subseteq R$. We say that E is equicontinuous in $x_0 \in X$ if: Given $\epsilon \gt 0$, $\exists \delta \ge 0$ such that $x \in X, |x-x_0| \lt \delta$. $|f(x)-f(x_0)| \lt \epsilon$, $\forall f \in E$

We say that E is equicontinuous if E is equicontinuous throughout $x_0 \in E$.
A sequence $f_n x \to R$ is equicontinuous in $x_0$ if $E=$ {$fn: n \in N$} is equicontinuous in $x_0$: Given $\epsilon$, $\exists \delta$ such that $x \in X$, $|x-x_0 |\lt \delta$. $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)| \gt \epsilon$, $\forall n$

I can't think how to do this exercise. The sequence doesn't converge, right? When n goes to zero the sequence goes to 1 and when n goes to 1 the sequence goes to x, I don't think I understand. Can someone help me, thanks!

Comment: It's equiconinous if the same delta works for every function.   Note that $f_1$ is your worst case scenario, everything else is a stronger contraction in (0,1), so the $\delta$ that works for $f_1$ works for all $f_n$

Comment: Since $n\in\Bbb N$, *how* can $n$ go to $0$?

Comment: @Alan No, the worst cases occur for large $n$; these are what would prevent equicontinuity on the closed interval $[0,1]$.  More specifically, $\delta\epsilon$ works (in the definition of equicontinuity) when $n=1$, but not for larger $n$ when $x_0$ is near $1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Good question,I don't know.But what if $n \notin \mathbb N$ is the set (0.1) not empty in $\mathbb N$?

Comment: What is the set $(0.1)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The open interval (0, 1)?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In N it is empty isn't it?

Comment: If you are asking whether $(0,1)\cap\Bbb N=\emptyset$, then, yes, that is true.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: The sequence converges to not-a-function
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{ for } 0 \le\ x \le 1 \\ [0,1] & \mbox{ for } x = 1 \end{cases}
$$
What else is there to say? Sometimes I don't understand mathematicians :-(

Answer (score 6):

Let $x_0\in (0,1)$ and let $\epsilon>0.$ Choose $\delta_0>0$ such that $x_0+\delta_0<1.$ Then $(x_0+\delta_0)^n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Thus there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $2(x_0+\delta_0)^n <\epsilon.$

Since $f_1,\dots f_N$ are continuous at $x_0,$ there exist  $\delta_1,\dots, \delta_N >0$ such that $n\le N$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta_n$ implies $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\epsilon.$

Now set $\delta=\min (\delta_0,\delta_1,\dots,\delta_N).$ If $n\le N$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta,$ then clearly $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\epsilon.$ If $n>N$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta,$ then $|x-x_0|<\delta_0,$ and

$|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|= |x^n-x_0^n| \le x^n+x_0^n< 2(x_0+\delta_0)^n<\epsilon.$

It follows that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\epsilon$ for all $n.$ Therefore $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous at $x_0$ as desired.

Finally, the sequence $x,x^2,x^3,\dots $ is practically "the" canonical example of a sequence converging to $0$ pointwise on $(0,1),$ but not uniformly. This will also be true for any subsequence $f_{n_k}.$ I'll leave it here for now, but ask if you have questions.